# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 (_MWB_registerSDK)

Tags: xcode, clang

I'm attempting to build a React Native package ([react-native-drivers-license-barcode-scanner](https://github.com/kyledecot/react-native-drivers-license-barcode-scanner)) that wraps the [ManateeWorks Barcode Scanner SDK](https://manateeworks.com/barcode-scanner-sdk) but I'm running into some trouble when attempting to build my example application.

When building the project I'm receiving the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_MWB_registerSDK", referenced from:
      -[DriversLicenseBarcodeScannerView setLicense:] in libreact-native-drivers-license-barcode-scanner.a(DriversLicenseBarcodeScannerView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the generated clang command:

```
Ld /Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Example.app/Example normal arm64
cd /Users/kyledecot/Desktop/react-native-drivers-license-barcode-scanner/example/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.3.sdk
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DoubleConversion
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Folly
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/glog
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/react-native-drivers-license-barcode-scanner
-L/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/yoga
-F/Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
-filelist /Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Example.build/Debug-iphoneos/Example.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Example.LinkFileList
-Xlinker
-rpath
-Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks
-miphoneos-version-min=8.0
-Xlinker
-object_path_lto
-Xlinker /Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Example.build/Debug-iphoneos/Example.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Example_lto.o
-Xlinker
-export_dynamic
-Xlinker
-no_deduplicate
-fembed-bitcode-marker
-fobjc-arc
-fobjc-link-runtime
-ObjC
-lDoubleConversion
-lFolly
-lReact
-lglog
-lreact-native-drivers-license-barcode-scanner
-lstdc++
-lyoga
-framework JavaScriptCore
-lPods-Example
-Xlinker
-dependency_info
-Xlinker /Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Example.build/Debug-iphoneos/Example.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Example_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-bjokdgrhqsuilkatgwyznixeeeld/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Example.app/Example
```

### Build Active Architectures Only

Below you can see the settings for both my library's Xcode project as well as my example's Xcode project:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can see in that there is no reference to `libBarcodeScanner.h` which is where the problem lies (I think) but I don't know how to instruct Xcode to include this.

Comment: Did you install this SDK via pod?

Comment: @TheTiger Yes the example project in my repo uses cocoapods to install my package which includes the `libBarcodeScanner.h` in it's Xcode Project (It's a static library).

Comment: `Build Active Architecture Only` of your project target and `pods`  are same or different? They should be same.

Comment: Yes they are the same (`Yes`). I've updated my question to include screenshots.

Comment: Well this was regarding `pods` please see [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/G2Kv0Yo.png).

Comment: Yes this one is also set to `Yes`. I've updated to include a screenshot of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171779/discussion-between-kyle-decot-and-thetiger).